# Pointers in golang

Tags: go

Why this:

```
obj := *g
return &obj, nil
```

is not equal to this:

```
return &(*g), nil
```

Shouldn't it be working in the same way (Return pointer that is pointing to the new memory region with the data from `g` struct)?

Comment: The first does a copy and returns the address of the copy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first one, you allocate a new memory region by declaring obj. In the second, you simply reference the value at g, which is just g.

Comment: Adam Smith, I can't comment on your answer so I am commenting here. I believe yours shows the same pointer value because you are using nil value of the struct, which is handled specially. If you update the struct to have a field like `type G struct { x string }`, and then use `g := &G{""}`, your same code produces different pointer values.

Comment: Actually it produces different pointers even if you use nil value for this non-empty struct, user2357112 wrote the real reason in comment on your answer now.

Comment: if you replace "nil value" with  "a value with zero size", then you are correct.

Comment: ThunderCat: yup thanks, I thought it was for a different reason.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not convinced that it's not the same.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type G struct {

}

func foo(g *G) (*G, error) {
  return &(*g), nil
}

func bar(g *G) (*G, error) {
  obj := (*g)
  return &obj, nil
}

func main() {
  g := &G{}

  a, _ := foo(g)
  b, _ := bar(g)

  fmt.Printf("a: %p, b: %p\n", a, b)  // gives the same pointer value
}
```

[Try it here](https://repl.it/repls/ZealousThriftyConditions)

Comment: Try it with a [non-empty struct](https://play.golang.org/p/WFxU4NLYxIK), and you'll get different results. I'm surprised things turned out the way they did for an empty struct; I can see why that would be valid behavior in some languages, particularly since an empty struct should be immutable, but I'm surprised such behavior is considered valid in Go.

Comment: Apparently this behavior for empty structs is explicitly allowed by the spec: "Two distinct zero-size variables may have the same address in memory."

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks all!